# RegEx expression in phone number format (no more than 10 digits) that does not accept 0 or 1 as first number

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I would like a reg ex expression that is in phone number format (XXX)XXX-XXXX
..that can be no more than 10 digits, and does not accept 0 or 1 as the first number.

Right now I have -

```
/^(?!\(?[0-9]11\)?|\(?1[0-9][0-9]\)?|\(?0[0-9][0-9]?)(\(?\d{3}\)?\s?)(\(?\d{3})(\s?-?\s?)(\d{4})$/;
```

But it does not work.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use expression:

```
^\([2-9][0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `\(` An opening bracket `(`.
- `[2-9]` First digit between 2 and 9.
- `[0-9]{2}` Two digits.
- `\)` A closing bracket `)`.
- `[0-9]{3}` Three digits.
- `-` A hyphen character.
- `[0-9]{4}` Four digits.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/LEumDb/1).

Answer (score 1):

We'll match 3 numbers not starting with 0 or 1 surrounded by parenthesis with `\([2-9]\d{2}\)` then 3 numbers alone with `\d{3}` then 4 numbers following a dash with `-\d{4}`.

Your full expression is `/\([2-9]\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/`

```js
const regex = /\([2-9]\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{4}/;
const valid = '(211)222-3333';
const invalid = '(111)222-3333';

console.log(regex.test(valid));
console.log(regex.test(invalid));
```